# Homogeneous Equations and Such

Tags: linear-algebra

"Consider the linear system  $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 3\\2 & 1 & 4\\1 & -7 & 5\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and find a general solution of the homogeneous system."

So a homogeneous system is just a system of equations that are equal to $0$. Through elementary row operations I find that the system of equations is:

$x_1 - 2x_2 + 3x_3 = 0$

$5x_2 - 2x_3 = 0$

$0 = 0$

Then I think the answer they want is $\underline{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} +$$\begin{pmatrix}-2.6t \\ \frac{2}{5}t \\ t\end{pmatrix}$ where $x_3 = t$.  Is this what they want?

Comment: It think formatting looks good. You gave a vector with a free variable that desbribes all vectors in the Nullspace. But you might want to change that typo in the first line of your solutions. Should be $3x3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the form that I suspect the answer should be; however, your calculation of $x_1$ is a tad off, given your equations: $$x_1 = -3t + \dfrac 45 t = -\dfrac{11}5 t= -2.2 t$$

After edit: The form you wrote in the first post is sufficient. There is no need to add the zero vector to it. What you can do is multiply the vector coefficient vector by $t$, but that too is unnecessary. $$\vec v = \begin{pmatrix}-2.2t \\ \frac{2}{5}t \\ t\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-2.2 \\ \frac{2}{5} \\ 1\end{pmatrix} t$$

Comment: Alrighty thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant $-2.2 t$, but the rest looks good.

Comment: $\ddot\smile  +1$